# Error: "Expected expression" in recursive call

Tags: c++, recursion

My program has a syntax error:

> Expected expression

I'm new to recursion; I hope I did it correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
void vvodmas(int a[],int n);
int poisk(int a[],int n,int min , int i);
int poiskmin( int a[], int  n);
int main()
{ int n;int i;
  int a[i];
  std::cout<<"massiv: ";
  vvodmas(a,n);
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"minimum"<< poiskmin( a[],n);     // here is the problem

}
void vvodmas(int a[],int n)
{ std::cout<<"n?";
  std::cin>>n;
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    std::cout<< a[i]<<" ";
}
int poisk(int a[], int n,int min, int i)
{
  if (i<n)
  { if (a[i]<min)
    min=a[i];
    i++;
    poisk(a,n,min,i);
  }
else
  return min;

}
int poiskmin( int a[], int  n)
{
  return poisk( a, n, a[0], 0 );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code **and** accurately describe the problem.  Most of all, you need to include the entire error message; this will include the line number and position where the compiler realized that you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `[]` to pass `a` to a `poiskmin`; it was needed when `a` was declared, to tell the compiler that `a` was an array.  After that, the compiler does not need to be reminded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the argument **a[]**.  Your logic needs to pass the entire array, not just an unspecified element.  You need only **a** here.

Once you add the brackets, the compiler expects that you're trying to pass an element.  You didn't tell it which element (inside the brackets).  That's why it complained about a missing expression: it's looked for something like **a[0]**.

---

By the way, the error message I get from **gcc** is

```
a.c:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
```

Note how the position information is very helpful in finding the error.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is in the line,

```
std::cout<<"minimum"<< poiskmin( a[],n);     // here is the problem
```

The corrected line to be

```
std::cout<<"minimum"<< poiskmin( a,n) ;
```

**[]** has to be removed when passing the complete array to the function as an argument, **[]** will be used when you want to send a particular element of the array to the function ,as you did in the below statement.

```
return poisk( a, n, a[0], 0 );
```

Apart from these , there are some other loop holes in your program.

1 . Always it is preferable to initialize the variable .

```
int n = 0 ;
int i = 0 ;
```

2 . you are assigning the vale of the array and the length of the array inside the `vvodmas(a,n);` function.

But the scope of the variable is passed by value to the function , the values will not be filled in the function will not be reflected in the caller part, Pass the values as reference to the function.